# What does partition type 0x70 and 0x43 mean on an external hard drive?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, external-hdd, exfat

Last fall someone moved a bunch of old files from an Ubuntu and windows PC to an external Toshiba 2TB hard drive. I'm not sure the content of all the files, but there definitely should be data on this hard drive that I need access to.

The problem is when I try to connect to the hard drive, it appears to be partitioned in 5 different segments. None of which are the standard readable format types. They have the following details:

- Contents: Unallocated Space Size: 3.4 GB Device: /dev/sde
- Contents: Unknown Size: 982 GB Device: /dev/sde1 Partition Type: 0x70
- Contents: Unallocated Space Size: 15 GB Device: /dev/sde
- Contents: Unknown Size: 931 GB Device: /dev/sde2 Partition Type: 0x43
- Contents: Unallocated Space Size: 69 GB Device: /dev/sde

I am interested in looking at the two Unknown partitions. They both seem to have weird partition types. I looked into the hexadecimal flags that were provided. According to [this website](http://web.archive.org/web/20030411231940/www.powerquest.com/support/primus/id233.cfm), this is what they mean:

- 0x43 Alternative Linux native file system (EXT2fs)
- 0x70 DiskSecure Multi-Boot

I have no idea how partitions with this type were created. Does anyone know how to read a hard drive with this partition type?

[Here is what the disk management looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnhRD.png)

Edit:

The files shouldn't be encrypted. Also I have tried mounting both partitions and this failed.

I have tried mounting the second partition with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sde2 /mnt/mydrive
```

and I get the following error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

I tried `fdisk -l` and this is the information it outputs:

```
Disk /dev/sde: 1.8 TiB, 2000398931968 bytes, 3907029164 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2052474d

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sde1          6579571 1924427647 1917848077 914.5G 70 DiskSecure Multi-Boot
/dev/sde2       1953251627 3771827541 1818575915 867.2G 43 unknown
```

Comment: Presumably EXT2fs is what we usually call ext2, a forerunner to ext3 and ext4. http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/ext2.html You should be able to mount that without issue.

Comment: I tried mounting that partition and it didn't seem to work. I saw that these are usually used for back up on that link. Is there a particular method for accessing back ups?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. If you search Ask Ubuntu for “DiskSecure” there are plenty of hits with a similar problem. You might find something by working through those questions. This seems to be very old technology but judging by the size of the disk not so old. Suggests to me someone with special knowledge has gone to some length to secure the data.

Comment: Your title does not match what is asked.   "sudo mount /dev/sde2 /mnt/mydrive" ehm why do you believe you can mount it like that? DiskSecure Multi-Boot should be a NTFS fileststem so you probably need something like `sudo mkdir /mnt/sde && sudo chmod 755 /mnt/sde && mount -t ntfs /dev/sde /mnt/sde`  (NOT sde1) sde1 and sde2 are likely combined partitions. fdisk probably does not support these filesystems.